# Symbolic differentiation on a function of matrices and vectors

Tags: symbolic, differentials

Let $I_t$, $I$, $V$, $Z$ be vectors and $R$, $B$, $P$, $A$, $\mathcal{K}$, $\mathcal{P}$ be some matrices such that

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
    S&=&-(R I+B^\top V)^\top \mathcal{R}(R I+B^\top V)
    \\&&-(I_t+B I- P V+A Z)^\top \mathcal{P}(I_t+B I- P V+A Z)
    \\&&+(I_t+B I- P V)^\top \mathcal{K}(I_t+B I- P V)
    \end{eqnarray}$$

is a scalar quantity. Is there a way to use mathematica's symbolic computation to rewrite it as
\begin{eqnarray}
S&=&-\begin{bmatrix}
I_t & I & V & Z
\end{bmatrix}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\star & \star & \star & \star\\
\star & \star & \star & \star\\
\star & \star & \star & \star\\
\star & \star & \star & \star
\end{bmatrix}}_{\textbf M}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_t \\I\\V\\Z
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}.

PS: I am trying to check if the $S\leq 0$ for all $I_t$, $I$, $V$ and $Z$.

Comment: Try `m = 1/2 D[-s, {{it, i, v, z}, 2}]`. Note that `I`, like several other capital letters` is the built-in symbol, so that I had to decapitalized all symbols.

Comment: Sorry for the caps. I tried it earlier, it did not work as they are all vectors and Matrices. Mathematica is not considering them to be vectors (Matrices) variables.

Comment: see also: [PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ.html)